# GWT causes Eclipse to fail to launch on Windows XP

Tags: windows, eclipse, gwt

Clicking on eclipse causes the splash screen to show then the application is killed silently with no error message. The .log file has the following information ( summarized)

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-11-09 11:33:45.323
!MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-11-09 11:33:45.323
!MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution'
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "com.google.gdt.eclipse.login" was 

unable to instantiate class "com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution".

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution.<init>(LoginTrimContribution.java:129)
    ...
org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:187)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessProtectedResource.<init>(AccessProtectedResource.java:184)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.draft10.GoogleAccessProtectedResource.<init>(GoogleAccessProtectedResource.java:87)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.loadLogin(GoogleLogin.java:628)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.<clinit>(GoogleLogin.java:98)
```

and a bunch of other error messages revolving around com.google.gdt.eclipse.login

A google searched yielded nothing about eclipse.login. The package is not in the .metadata/.plugins directory and deleting other google packages or .properties did nothing.

Hoping someone encountered this before and has a work around. Nothing major changes to system or eclipse or Java before this error occurred other than I hadn't launched in a few weeks.

Eclipse EE Indigo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in the Eclipse software plugin folder  I found that the com.google.gdt.eclipse.login package file had a version number attached to the end of the file name something like 3.03_v1 etc. I renamed this to just com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.jar and eclipse launched.

I am not sure how the file name changed and why it suddenly stopped working but that solved the issue.

Comment: actually *deleting* the file does the trick somehow.. but to be safe just rename it