# Eclipse startup failure Google plugins

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I recently installed some Google plugins on Eclipse indigo and after restart it fails to load. The log file in  workspace shows a bunch of errors surrounding !MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution'.   It also appears that I maybe missing something due to a partial install.  Anybody know whats up?

```
!SESSION 2014-08-11 14:23:59.293 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer 4 0 2014-08-11 14:25:46.910
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status[plugin=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer;code=4;message=hardClose;severity4;exception=java.io.IOException: Stream closed;children=[]]
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:184)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream.exhaustInputStream(ChunkedInputStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.notifyWatcher(AutoCloseInputStream.java:194)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.close(AutoCloseInputStream.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.hardClose(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.hardClose(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.cancel(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.handleTransferEvent(FileReader.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.fireTransferReceiveDataEvent(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.fireTransferReceiveDataEvent(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1163)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.handleReceivedData(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer$1.performFileTransfer(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.FileTransferJob.run(FileTransferJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
!SESSION 2014-08-11 23:26:30.697 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2014-08-12 16:45:42.431
!MESSAGE Operation details
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 1 2014-08-12 16:45:42.431
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2014-08-12 16:45:42.431
!MESSAGE Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2014-08-12 16:45:42.431
!MESSAGE Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42)     requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.0' but it could not be found    

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2014-08-12 16:45:42.441
!MESSAGE Operation details
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 1 2014-08-12 16:45:42.441
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2014-08-12 16:45:42.441
!MESSAGE Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2014-08-12 16:45:42.441
!MESSAGE Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42)     requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.0' but it could not be found    

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2014-08-12 16:58:19.158
!MESSAGE Operation details
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 1 2014-08-12 16:58:19.158
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2014-08-12 16:58:19.158
!MESSAGE Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2014-08-12 16:58:19.158
!MESSAGE Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42)     requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.0' but it could not be found    

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 4 0 2014-08-12 16:58:19.159
!MESSAGE Operation details
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 1 2014-08-12 16:58:19.159
!MESSAGE Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2014-08-12 16:58:19.159
!MESSAGE Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 4 0 2014-08-12 16:58:19.159
!MESSAGE Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.v201407290036-rel-r42)     requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.0' but it could not be found    
!SESSION 2014-08-12 21:17:29.320 --------------------------------------------    ---    
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800    
java.version=1.7.0_45    
java.vendor=Oracle Co    rporation    
BootLoader constants:     OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US    
Framework arguments:      -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.p    roduct    
Command-line argument    s:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -prod    uct org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product    

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-08-12 21:17:42.332
!MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-08-12 21:17:42.334
!MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution'
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "com.google.gdt.eclipse.login" was unable to instantiate class "com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.getContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createControl(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager$ToolBarTrimProxy.dock(TrimContributionManager.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3874)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3885)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$68.runWithException(Workbench.java:3664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution.<init>(LoginTrimContribution.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable oauthClientProvider extension point found
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.getClientIdAndSecretFromExtensionPoints(GoogleLogin.java:104)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.<clinit>(GoogleLogin.java:77)
    ... 58 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2014-08-12 21:17:42.337
!MESSAGE Plug-in "com.google.gdt.eclipse.login" was unable to instantiate class "com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution.<init>(LoginTrimContribution.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.getContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createControl(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager$ToolBarTrimProxy.dock(TrimContributionManager.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3874)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3885)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$68.runWithException(Workbench.java:3664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable oauthClientProvider extension point found
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.getClientIdAndSecretFromExtensionPoints(GoogleLogin.java:104)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.<clinit>(GoogleLogin.java:77)
    ... 58 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-08-12 21:17:42.338
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.computeWidth(ControlContribution.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager$ToolBarTrimProxy.dock(TrimContributionManager.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3874)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3885)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$68.runWithException(Workbench.java:3664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-08-12 21:17:42.521
!MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution'

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-08-12 21:17:42.521
!MESSAGE Class load Failure: 'com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution'
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "com.google.gdt.eclipse.login" was unable to instantiate class "com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.getContributionItem(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.DynamicToolBarContributionItem.createControl(DynamicToolBarContributionItem.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.createControl(ToolBarManager.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager$ToolBarTrimProxy.dock(TrimContributionManager.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimContributionManager.update(TrimContributionManager.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3874)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3885)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$22.runWithException(Workbench.java:1216)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution.<init>(LoginTrimContribution.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This fixed my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314984/gwt-causes-eclipse-to-fail-to-launch-on-windows-xp

Answer (score 0):

Enter in the YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata search for "google" and delete all folders
In the first line of your "eclipse.ini" include:
-clean
Start you eclipse

This work for me.